# Math in batch files

Tags: batch-file, math

I am trying to make a simple compounding interest calculator and I need to learn batch but I do not know much and I am trying to make my code as simple as possible.

```
@echo off
set /p p="What is the principal value? "

set /p r="What is the rate of growth in decimal form? "
set /p n="How many times is the principal compounded each year? "
set /p t="How many years is the value compounded? "
set /a a= r/n
set /a b=n*t
set /a c= 1 + a
set /a d= c^b
set /a e = p * d
echo %e%
pause
```

I always get the answer of 0 at the end of my program. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `SET` command cannot do floating point arithmetic. Also you may have not read this in the help file for the `SET` command. **If you use any of the logical or modulus operators, you will need to
enclose the expression string in quotes.**

Comment: You could easily call out to Powershell to do the math. `FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('powershell %r% / %n%') DO set a=%%G`. But then you might as well just do the whole script in powershell.